# Location.distanceTo returns value in meters but I need feet

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanted to use `Location.distanceTo`. The idea is that if the user hasn't moved, then don't make the next function call until they do:

```
if (oldLocation!!.distanceTo(location) == 0f) {
    continue
}
```

Per the docs `distanceTo`:

> Returns the approximate distance in *meters* between this location and
>   the given location. ([Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)))

The tutorial uses feet. So, I thought, there must be a bunch of code someplace that does the conversion and, in this case, is totally unnecessary and inefficient. Right?

Apparently not. This causes an error:

```
if (oldLocation!!.distanceTo(location) == 0m) {
    continue
}
```

So then I just put 0 in without saying what the measurement is and expected `distanceTo` to process that 0 in meters, which is what the docs say, but it doesn't work either.

```
if (oldLocation!!.distanceTo(location) == 0) {
    continue
}
```

So here is the end question:

It were not for the tutorial doing this in feet, I would never have figured it out by reading the docs. Never. I mean, when it expressly says meters, how are we supposed to know that the solution to making it work is to use feet?

Did I miss something?

Comment: `0f` means a `float` value of 0. `0m` is invalid syntax. You can see in the docs `distanceTo` returns type `float`. BTW, 0 meters and 0 feet are the same distance.

Comment: For some reason I can't flag this as the answer so I upvoted it.

So the return IS in meters... in the form of a floating decimal. That is definitely the answer I needed, thanks.

Comment: Please note that locations are not 100% accurate.  GPS is accurate to about 10m, network to maybe 100m or less.  SO you will see slightly changed locations even when they don't move.  So checking for exactly ==0 is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0f` means a float value of `0`. `0m` is invalid syntax. You can see in the docs `distanceTo` returns type float.